# Where is NoAds Fixed for Opera?

Tags: browser-addons, opera

There was an extension NoAds for opera which was later corrected by someone else as NoAds Fixed.

For some reasons Opera has deleted this extension for their directory – where do I find it? It was an awesome extension, it was able to block any element on any page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Here](https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/noads-fixed/1.0.8-fixed3/) (addons.opera.com):

> usopion says: 1Jan. 13, 2011 - Version 1.0.8-fixed3
>
> Sorry, I have finished supporting this extension.
> This extension does not work on Opera 11.10.
> Please change extensions to block contents.
> I recommend ContentBlockHelper or Opera AdBlock.

Usopion is the person who was maintaining "NoAds Fixed"

Comment: Do you have a link to extension? I still want to give it a try